# Sql Alchemy cannot run inside a transaction block

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to run a query in redshift from a python script, but I'm getting error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InternalError: (psycopg2.InternalError) ALTER EXTERNAL TABLE cannot run inside a transaction block
```

This is my code:

```
engine = create_engine(SQL_ENGINE % urlquote(REDSHIFT_PASS))
partition_date = (date.today() - timedelta(day)).strftime("%Y%m%d")
query = """alter table  {table_name} add partition (dt={date_partition}) location 's3://dft-dwh-files/raw_data/google_analytics/revenue_per_channel/{date_partition}/';""".format(date_partition=partition_date,table_name=table_name)
conn = engine.connect()
conn.execute(query).execution_options(autocommit=True)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

For PostgreSQL, you need to set the [isolation level](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Connection.execution_options.params.isolation_level) to `AUTOCOMMIT`, not the SQLAlchemy `autocommit`:

```
conn.execution_options(isolation_level="AUTOCOMMIT").execute(query)
```

Comment: If you are using sqlalchemy :session instead of :conn, see this answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/53327098/248616

Comment: This has been renamed to `conn.set_isolation_level("AUTOCOMMIT")` - See http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/connection.html#connection.set_isolation_level

Comment: @gies0r That's if you're using psycopg directly. This question is about SQLAlchemy. See https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/postgresql.html#psycopg2-transaction-isolation-level

Comment: @univerio Oh yeah.. Missed that the specific question was SQLAlchemy. So my answer contains how to do it in `psycopg` (which looks working also)

Answer (score 6):

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5403680/248616) works for me as using sqlalchemy :session not :conn as [@univerio answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44976893/248616)

I quote their answer here

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://USER:PASSWORD@127.0.0.1:5432/DB_OR_TEMPLATE')
session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)()
session.connection().connection.set_isolation_level(0)
session.execute('CREATE DATABASE test')
session.connection().connection.set_isolation_level(1)
```

If you don't have any databases, you should use `template1`

```
"""Isolation level values."""
ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT     = 0
ISOLATION_LEVEL_READ_COMMITTED = 1
ISOLATION_LEVEL_SERIALIZABLE   = 2
```

Comment: looks like `set_isolation_level()` is no longer in use in 2022

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to run `COMMIT` manually before removing or adding the index:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

with Session(get_engine()) as session:
    session.execute("COMMIT")
    session.execute("DROP INDEX CONCURRENTLY IF EXISTS <my_index>;")
```

Comment: Somehow `session.commit()` didn´t work but your answer worked for me. Thanks