# REINDEX DATABASE cannot run inside a transaction block

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, postgresql-9.4

I am using an old version of sqlalchemy (0.8) and I need to execute "`REINDEX DATABASE <dbname>`" on **PostgreSQLql 9.4** by using sqlalchemy api.

Initially I tried with:

```
conn = pg_db.connect()  
conn.execute('REINDEX DATABASE sg2')
conn.close()
```

but I got error "`REINDEX DATABASE cannot run inside a transaction block`".

I read in internet and tried other changes:

```
engine.execute(text("REINDEX DATABASE sg2").execution_options(autocommit=True))
```

(I tried also with autocommit=False).

and

```
conn = engine.raw_connection()  
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('REINDEX DATABASE sg2')
cursor.close()
```

I always have the same error.

I tried also following:

```
conn.execution_options(isolation_level="AUTOCOMMIT").execute(query)
```

but I got error
 Invalid value 'AUTOCOMMIT' for isolation_level. Valid isolation levels for postgresql are REPEATABLE READ, READ COMMITTED, READ UNCOMMITTED, SERIALIZABLE

What am I missing here ? Thanks for any help.

Comment: autocommit=on did you try this? in your psql like command SET AUTOCOMMIT = ON

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sql Alchemy cannot run inside a transaction block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44959599/sql-alchemy-cannot-run-inside-a-transaction-block)

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński I tried suggestion provided in that link but using that I got error  "Invalid value 'AUTOCOMMIT' for isolation_level. Valid isolation levels for postgresql are REPEATABLE READ, READ COMMITTED, READ UNCOMMITTED, SERIALIZABLE"

Comment: @Avi I tried using cursor.execute('SET AUTOCOMMIT = ON; REINDEX DATABASE sg2') but I got the same error.

Comment: Maybe try from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402805/error-when-creating-a-postgresql-database-using-python-sqlalchemy-and-psycopg2/5654427
It does seem to be doing the same thing, just using numerical values instead, so might not work with your SQL Alchemy version.

Comment: No `SET AUTOCOMMIT = ON` this should be run in psql cmd.... not inside code

Comment: @avi There has been no `autocommit` parameter in PostgreSQL since 2003.

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński its there...  read this https://dzone.com/articles/autocommit-in-postgresqls-psql

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński by using numerical values it works thanks.